# Zoom SDK : iOS Swift

Tags: ios, video-streaming, audio-streaming, swift4.2

I'm very new to Zoom's SDK. Can anyone explain where I can find App key, App secret, Domain, user id, user token, user name and meeting id?

I have a developer account, which has SDK key and secret as well as API key and secret--i'm assuming SDK key and secret are the app key and secret. Is that right?

**What is domain? zoom.us?**  I'm using zoom.us as the domain, but getting the error: 
2018-08-14 10:03:04.220813-0500 MobileRTCSwiftSample[10312:1070282]
 old data has cpoied done
2018-08-14 10:03:04.225989-0500 MobileRTCSwiftSample[10312:1070282] [logging] 
table zoom_meet_participants already exists
2018-08-14 10:03:04.227146-0500 MobileRTCSwiftSample[10312:1070282] [logging]
 table zoom_kv already exists
[10312:771:08-14/10:03:04.238:FATAL:SBPTUI.cpp(197)]
 Assert failed: 0.
**Where do I get a user token/id?**

Comment: Hi, I am getting MobileRTCAuthError_Unknown while authenticating. Can you please help ?

Answer (score 0):

> Can anyone explain where I can find App key, App secret, Domain, user id, user token, user name and meeting id?

- [**App key, App Secret**]: APP Key is the same as SDK key. But API key is for calling Zoom API. You can get App key, App secret from http://developer.zoom.us/me. The key and secret are under: Developer Account > SDK. You can find more info here: https://marketplace.zoom.us/docs/sdk/preface/sdk-keys-secrets.
- [**Domain**]: Domain should always be "zoom.us".
- [**User id, user token**]: You can get user id and tokens from Zoom API. You can find the instruction here: https://marketplace.zoom.us/docs/sdk/preface/zak
- [**username**]: The username you use to login Zoom client.
- [**meeting id**]: That is the meeting number that you got from other Zoom clients or from an invitation.

There are two major ways of authentication, login user and non-login user.

If you choose to authenticate as login user, you will need to pass Zoom username and password for authentication. And you do not need Zoom Token and Zoom Access Token for that.

If you choose to authenticate as non-login user, you will need to get tokens from Zoom API first and then pass the token to host a scheduled meeting.

The Swift sample is deprecated thus the libraries are outdated. Please try the ios sample:https://github.com/zoom/zoom-sdk-ios

---

- You can find more info in the official document: https://marketplace.zoom.us/docs/sdk/preface/introducing-zoom-sdk
- You can also seek support from the official community forum, some of your questions might be asked and answered there.
  https://devforum.zoom.us/

Comment: Hey I am getting MobileRTCAuthError_Unknown while authenticating SDK.

Comment: Please help me. I am not able to athenticate